# Inconsistent readings using Pressure / Altitude sensor (MPL3115A2)

Tags: sensor, sparkfun, pressure

I have two pressure sensors ([MPL3115A2](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/mpl3115a2-pressure-sensor-hookup-guide)) with each connected to a [Particle Photon](https://store.particle.io/?utm_source=homesite&utm_medium=Nav&utm_campaign=TopMenu), the sensors are placed next to each other at the same level.

In barometric mode, one sensor reads 95043 Pa, while the other read 95405 Pa. This translates to a difference is 362 Pa.

In altimeter mode, one sensor reads 1742 ft, while the other sensor at the same level reads 1658 ft. This translates to a difference of 84 ft.

I also observed that these differences (pressure & altitude) keep varying over time. I'd appreciate if anyone with experience on these or similar sensors could shed some light on this variance in measurement.

I am trying to use these sensors to get the altitude of the [construction elevator](http://www.shutterstock.com/video/clip-31383-stock-footage-building-under-construction-nearing-completion-follow-exterior-elevator-medium-shot-betacamsp.html) in realtime, any suggestions on accurately measuring the elevator height would also be appreciated.

Comment: The datasheet does specify a "Pressure Absolute Accuracy" spec of 0.4kPa (400Pa), so what you're seeing doesn't seem unreasonable.

Comment: Did you tare the both sensors at reference altitude?

Comment: Hi, again. I thought you might have trouble with [that](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/209990/how-to-compensate-for-weather-changes-in-barometric-pressure-sensor-bmp180). Looking at the video, is there no way to count floors by photo-sensor or rungs on the elevator track? There are thousands of industrial diffuse photo-sensors on the market. See [Balluff](http://www.balluff.com/balluff/MUS/en/products/diffuse-sensors.jsp) for an introduction to the topic.

Comment: Another option is to monitor a mark (or several) on the elevator cable drum with a pair of sensors and make an [incremental rotary encoder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotary_encoder#Incremental_rotary_encoder). This is very simple and reliable.

Comment: @brhans Alright, well spotted.

Comment: @transistor Nice ones, will look at both of your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

> ... any suggestions on accurately measuring the elevator height would also
> be appreciated.

As per my comment, another option is to monitor a mark (or several) on the elevator cable drum with a pair of sensors and make an incremental rotary encoder. This is very simple and reliable.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKlhW9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. 2-bit rotary encoder waveforms.*

The program logic is very simple.

- Track the current state of 'A'. If the state changes to 'high' then:
- Look at input 'B'. If 'B' is low then count up. If 'B' is high then count down.

You'll probably need to debounce the inputs to prevent spurious triggering.

[image: Encoder]

*Figure 2. Elevator encoder. A and B photo-sensors looking at reflective tape or high-contrast markings on winding drum.*

Comment: Note that this is a half resolution method for handling a quad encoder.  Higher resolution calls for counting on both A and B transitions

Comment: Thanks, Scott. OP is only interested in what floor the elevator is at. With a few pulses per floor all should be OK although a lookup table may be required as it's unlikely to be an integer number of pulses per floor. I didn't double up on the pulses because I reckoned the encoder marks would not be nice equal-angle marks as it has to be attached to the drum on an industrial elevator. A couple of strips of reflective tape might be as good as it gets. I'll add a sketch shortly.

Comment: Added encoder sketch.