# DPS310 altitude sensor values changing over time

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, sensor

I am using a DPS310 pressure altitude sensor. I tested the sensor with an Arduino using the Adafruit DSP310 Barometric Pressure Sensor Library.

Initially, the sensor gives 70.5 meter altitude.  In the same position, the sensor reads 68.7 meter after 10 minutes.

I have not changed any code segments.  How does the sensor behave like that? My aim is to track a box lifting by crane in 3D.

The altitude variation affects height of 3D tracking

What is the solution?

Comment: How are you going to compensate for natural variations in atmospheric pressure? You'd need a second sensor on the ground to give a reference value. At 10 m the pressure would drop to 0.998815 of the value at sea level.

Comment: @Transistor,   Thats a good idea .

Comment: [Met Eireann](https://www.met.ie/forecasts/atlantic-charts/precipitation-pressure#) reports a mid-Atlantic low of 980 mBar and a high of 1026 mBar over France. That's a variation of > 4% which will swamp your altitude variation.

Comment: See also my answer to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/213007/inconsistent-readings-using-pressure-altitude-sensor-mpl3115a2/213299#213299.

Comment: @Transistor is there is any other sensor that can give height ,for tracking object in 3D

Comment: Using Arduino other hobbyist toys in industrial applications such as crane installations is likely illegal in most countries. I've worked plenty with crane electronics and putting an Arduino somewhere on one sounds like an excellent way to end up with a lawsuit. Depending on the type of crane there might be smarter solutions, such as taking input from an existing wire sensor. If it's a hydraulic crane with multiple sections, things get more intricate. Laser sensors work well if you can ensure that they are aligned correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's due to the decrease in pressure in higher altitudes, you need some type of reference on the ground (for measuring pressure, maybe use a similar sensor and send both values to a microcontroller) and need to subtract it from the pressure you are measuring at 70.5m altitude. There must be no drift anymore.